# I have embedded html codes that I'd like to make inline blocks

Tags: html, embed

Have html codes for images from a Shopify app that I want to be inline on the page.

I have tried following tips on making them inline blocks, but nothing works. Here's the html the gallery provides for embedding:

```
<div class="cz-embed-gallery cozy-gallery-lazy-load" id="cz-embed-gallery#">
```

Comment: Please also provide your CSS code

Answer (score 0):

in your css just select the div and apply the propert, eg.

```css
.cz-embed-gallery {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

unless there is conflicting css this should work, but then again there is only so much I can do because you have not provided me with your css, just essentially select your element and apply `display: inline-block;` as a css property to it.